# vuetify: v-data-table key undefined sort click

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

then using v-data-table with multiple data, in the event onclick sort have a messagge in the console "TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined", help me please

```
vue_2.6.11.min.js:6 TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined
    at ir (vue_2.6.11.min.js:6)
    at vue_2.6.11.min.js:6
    at x (vue_2.6.11.min.js:6)
    at vue_2.6.11.min.js:6
    at x (vue_2.6.11.min.js:6)
    at vue_2.6.11.min.js:6
    at x (vue_2.6.11.min.js:6)
    at vue_2.6.11.min.js:6
    at x (vue_2.6.11.min.js:6)
    at a.__patch__ (vue_2.6.11.min.js:6)
```

Comment: You need to show your code. Try adding a fiddle or the snippet making the error.

Comment: this is my code, then 3th try sort in column cliente the error persist  https://jsfiddle.net/angel_jadan/51ytp8uj/55/#&togetherjs=osvrQPjLg3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're having duplicate keys in your data. If you want all your table's functionality to work properly, especially sorting, you have to provide a unique key for each row.

A simple fix for your example would be:

```
data: () => ({
  // assign a unique `key` to each element
  table_body: [/* your data here */].map((item, key) => ({...item, key}))
})
```

In template:

```
<v-data-table ref="tablaReporteGenerico"
              item-key="key"
              ... />
```

See it working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/58vskL0u/).

---

While using `index`es as `key` works, the industry standard for key-ing collections is [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) (or similar):

- `npm i uuid`
- (if using typescript) `npm i @types/uuid -D`
- in component: `import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid'`
- in data: `[/* your items */].map(item => ({ ...item, key: uuid() }))`

Unique identifiers are a must when working with arrays in JavaScript, as the order of elements in an array is not guaranteed across implementations. And I'd add working with arrays in JavaScript is also a must, since they're faster than any alternative.

Comment: Thank's so much, you saved me!

Comment: I tried this and have a unique id but the body still won't render it [preview](https://i.postimg.cc/437wdSnv/image.png)

Comment: @Fahmi, I suggest asking it as a separate question and providing a [mcve].